# android - Rounded Linear Layout corner overlapped by fill_parent TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, rounded-corners, android-drawable, fill-parent

[image]

**This is what I need to the top of my layout**

[image]

**This is what I actually have**

There would be a simple option that I'm not calculating at the moment.

**Drawable for rounded corners**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#E9E9E9"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

**Layout**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_layout" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/filter_title"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sp_intorno_a_me_proximity"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
            .
            .
            .
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_intorno_a_me_username"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
                android:hint="@string/agentNumber" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:weightSum="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_intorno_a_me_close_search"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="@string/annulla"
                    style="@style/HelianButtonRed"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_intorno_a_me_search"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:text="@string/find"
                    style="@style/HelianButtonGreen" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I have already tried to move the drawable to the first LinearLayout child.

How can I prevent the text view to hides the rounded corners?

Comment: Why dont you declare the title TextView inside the second LinearLayout ?Doing this way the textView background will not overlap your rounder corners

Comment: Because the result will be padded due to the **android:padding="15dp"** of the secondo linear layout. Can I avoid the padding for a single view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this in your TextView as background.
Create a new drawable .xml for TextView with following data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners 
        android:topLeftRadius="10dip"
        android:topRightRadius="10dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dip"

        />
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip"                  
      android:bottom="0dip" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I have not tried it yet, and I'm sure that this workaround would work, but I would like a more elegant solution that not force me to replicate the radius and color two times (one for the layout draw and one for the button draw).

I would like to generalize it...

Thank you for the time you are giving me anyway man!

Comment: No Actually you cant remove padding to one View if you have given padding to the parentLayout.But what you can do is put the TextView in a LinearLayout without any padding and put both textView's LinearLayout and LinearLayout2 inside one LinearLayout and give background to this LinearLayout.This way your TextView will not have padding

Comment: I know this is a bad practice.But you should give it a try.

Comment: Yeah man, I will give it a try!
You will have my feedback asap

Comment: Almost perfect!

When I set **android:topLeftRadius="5dip"** all the corners are rounded, instead of only the top left one.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of Manishika (I voted up your answer [do the same for me! :)]) I'm posting the solution of my problem!

**With this parent rounded corner style:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#E9E9E9"/>
    <stroke android:width="4dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

We need to attach a specific drawable to the textview (or any view you need).

**Here is the drawable for the trick:**

I subtracted 2 d

```
    <corners 
        android:topLeftRadius="8dip"
        android:topRightRadius="8dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dip" />
</shape>
```

**KEEP IN MIND!!**

The **Graphical Layout** (the Preview) will **NOT** shows the correct rounding! You need to test it on the device (or emulator if you have no devices).